# Using absolute positioned child div within ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am currently facing a problem with using `column-count` with an absolutely positioned div as a child.

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
ul > li {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li > .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="child">Positioned Absolute</div>
    Just some extra content
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="child">Positioned Absolute</div>
    Just some extra content
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="child">Positioned Absolute</div>
    Just some extra content
  </li>
</ul>
```

When using a negative `top`, it seems to wrap to the previous column, is there anyway to get around this?

I could use `width: 33%`, however that would change depending on the amount of columns, is there anyway to do this using `column-count`?

Comment: Have you tried a positive `bottom` instead?

Comment: Just tried @Tijmen to no avail, seems that whenever a child hits the top of a column it seems to auto wrap. Seems odd that it would do this.

Comment: @Ian posted your answer below, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 
    `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;` to make that work

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
ul > li {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
ul > li > .child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="child">Positioned Absolute</div>
    Just some extra content
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="child">Positioned Absolute</div>
    Just some extra content
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="child">Positioned Absolute</div>
    Just some extra content
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I checked caniuse seems to be supported mostly. How exactly did you find the documentation for column-break-inside?

Comment: i just google it `column count position relative issue` and got the answer :)

Comment: Ughh, I didn't think of googling relative issue. thanks!